# Android device to detect usb scanner

Tags: android

Android 3.1 have USB api. Actually I want to detect USB scanner and change its permission to extract fingerprint impression fro it. Can Detection and changing the permission possible in android 3.1 without rooting the device?
Can this be done with USB api in android 3.1?

Also the emulator does not detect the usb scanner. Is there any way to test this in emulator first?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

USB API functionality is not available in the emulator at the moment.

For an actual device, you may only plug in the devices from the supported devices list, which, as far as I remember, did not include any fingerprint scanners. If you root the device and compile/install the missing modules you may get fingerprinting hardware support, but it's still **very** unclear to me, how to get access to that hardware from Java.

So, unless you're going for device rooting and kernel module tweaking, I'm afraid it might be quite difficult to get your fingerprint scanner working with Android device.

Other than that, there's a Motorola Atrix phone, which has a built-in fingerprint scanner, and [Authentec has released SDK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1206033) for that device.

Comment: Actually I have the api of the scanner to read fingerprint impressins from it. But as per the scanner company I need to first root the device and then change the permission of the scanner to detect it and use it in the application.    But I just wanted to know if changing the permission of the scanner is possible if I use android api 3.1 without nedd to root the device. Because rooting the device is not preferable process to do.

Comment: Android uses not very standard flavour of linux, which may have (or may not have) /etc/udev rules to process removable USB devices. Besides that, you will need to insert kernel module, which supports your particular brand of scanner, and this requires using root access.

Comment: So, I think I can't access the scanner without rooting the device.?

Comment: the probability of making it work without rooting is negligible low.

Comment: Actually, the point of the Android USB API's is to let apps interact with arbitrary devices, without rooting.  Where you need to root is if you want to use an existing linux driver, or perhaps to stop the platform from claiming something it things it knows what to do with.